# Vue component does not render when I use <inertia-link> tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, inertiajs

When I use I use the `<inertia-link>` the `test.vue` child component does not render but it renders if I remove those tags. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

**test.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="p-6 sm:px-20 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
            <div>
                <b-logo class="block h-12 w-auto" />
            </div>

            <div class="mt-1 text-2xl">
                {{ $page.user.first_name }} {{ $page.user.last_name }}
            </div>

            <inertia-link :href="#">
                test-link
            </inertia-link>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import BLogo from './BLogo'

    export default {

        components: {
            BLogo,
        },
    }
</script>
```

This component is used in another .vue file with `<my-test />`

This is being done in laravel 8. Also, I have noticed that if I use the `<inertia-link>` tag in the parent vue then it shows up. So the tag works.

(and I think it is used by the default Jetstream profile pages).

Comment: Is `inertia-link` globally registered? Any console errors?

Comment: Your :href="#" prop looks off, since that's trying to bind the href property to the evaluation of the expression `#` which likely throws a syntax error. You should see an error in the dev console saying something similar.

Comment: @tony19 yes. It is part of the laravel 8. Installation

Comment: @RobertNubel no errors.

Comment: If you're not seeing errors for `:href="#"` (which is not a valid binding), there are likely other errors that are lost to you. I'd try to resolve the log issue first, as the console log is a vital troubleshooting tool.

Comment: @tony19 what about if i set it to a valid ref? Also, that same code works fine in the parent vue. just not in the child vue

Comment: That shouldn't work. `:href="#"` is a data binding. Vue would try to set the component's `href` prop to the value of the symbol named `#`, which itself is an invalid variable name. A valid setting would be `href="#"` (no preceding colon). But the point is that such errors should be thrown in the browser's console, and it's being hidden for some reason. Perhaps the root cause of your problem is also hidden.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using the below code for Vue3 from [inertiajs](https://inertiajs.com/client-side-setup) office site:

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

then u have to add the Link component like so:

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .component('inertia-link', Link)
      .mount(el)
  },
});
```

after that inertia-link component should work should work.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work by following the Inertia doc, it only came back an error as ```[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Link```

Answer (score 0):

First verify if you have intalled the dependencies

```
npm install @inertiajs/inertia @inertiajs/inertia-vue
```

or

```
yarn add @inertiajs/inertia @inertiajs/inertia-vue
```

Initialize app

Next, update your main JavaScript file to boot your Inertia app. All we're doing here is initializing the client-side framework with the base Inertia page component.

```
import { InertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(InertiaApp)

const app = document.getElementById('app')

new Vue({
  render: h => h(InertiaApp, {
    props: {
      initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
      resolveComponent: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
    },
  }),
}).$mount(app)
```

then if you need a Code splitting, follow the next steps
https://inertiajs.com/client-side-setup#code-splitting

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It is part of a laravel 8 setup so everything is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it almost made me crazy. This is how I figured it out. `<inertia-link>` is a custom link and Vue tries to find if it corresponds to a registered component. If Vue does not find the commponent it flags the warning
Here is what you need to do to resolve this issue.

- Import Link from Vue adapter of Inertia like this in your app.js

  `import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'`
- Register the Link as a component with Vue after you have imported both Vue and Link like this in your same app.js

  `Vue.component('inertia-link', Link)`

Try  in your templates and should work fine.

PS:- I was using Vue2