# Why are my Inertia Links not rendering the page? (InertiaJS)

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

## The problem

When I click my Inertia Links, the URL changes in the browser but the page or Vue component does not render.
However, when I click the link and reload the page manually, the page does get rendered.

Please help me! I don't even know how to debug this kind of problem!

Explaining how to debug this would also be nice

## What I've tried

- I tried to use the `<Link>`, `<InertiaLink>` and `<inertia-link>` components.
- I tried adding `.component('inertia-link', Link)` on `createApp()` in my `main.ts` file. (From the first answer of this thread: [Vue component does not render when I use <inertia-link> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63961097/vue-component-does-not-render-when-i-use-inertia-link-tag))
- I tried changing my Laravel routes from `Route::inertia('url', 'Component')` to `Route::get('url', function () { inertia('Component'); } )`
- I tried another browser.
- I checked the console for any errors, but there are no errors there.

## My code

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::inertia('/', 'HomePage');
Route::inertia('/test', 'TestPage');
```

**main.ts**

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import { InertiaProgress } from "@inertiajs/progress";

InertiaProgress.init({
    color: "#ffffff",
});

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => require(`./pages/${name}`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```

**Layout.vue**

```
<template>
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <Link href="/">
                    Home
                </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link href="/test">
                    Test
                </Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <main>
        <slot/>
    </main>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {Link} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
</script>
```

**What shows up in my Developer Tools Request Log when I click the link:**

[Developer Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iruJa.png)

Edit: This is probably because I did a faulty installation of Inertia, if you need a quick fix you could use a Laravel command that installs Inertia with Typescript for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly have your "TestPage" component in a different directory than "HomePage"?

I'm not entirely sure but if you've created another directory within the "Pages" directory, you will need to specify in the main.ts to look for other files to render like the following:

```
resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue'))
```

Comment: No its in the same folder